# "+ New" menu on our modern pages contain different options on some pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site

I have noted this issue inside our modern pages:- Where on some modern pages the "+ New" menu contains these options:-

[image]

But once we set the page as the home page for the site, the "+ New" menu will start showing these options instead:-

[image]

so how things work regarding the "+ New" menu options? does this mean that we can not copy the home page of the site?

Thanks

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this issue. I tried the steps you mentioned and on both the pages it is showing me the menu you shared in first screenshot.

Comment: I believe this is tied to the page layout of the page you are copying. If it is "Article" you will get the first one, if it's "Home" you will get the second one.

Comment: @R.Sperre all the pages i am talking about are based on "Article" page layout...

Comment: @GaneshSanap for me i will get the first screen shot, until i copy the page, where i will start getting the second screen shot on the page,, as if i can not do multiple copies for the same page,, while on the copied page, i will get the second screen shot.. not sure what is going on exactly ??

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint online and i cannot reproduce your issue.

Have you customized the modern page?

Try to create a new modern page, copy the page using "Copy of this page", check the "+ New" menu for the copied page.

Comment: the page which is showing the second screen shot is set as the home page of the site + has unique permission.. but i am not sure if this is causing the problem?